# How can I access (reference) my gridview in a handler.ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, handler, kml

Hey guys I'm working on a asp.net web app which generates KML file. 
I have a gridview where I have longitude and latitude taken from MySQL database. Then I use a Handler to create and stream the KML file to the user and open it in Google Earth...

I'm trying to read the longitude and latitude values from the gridview and use a for loop saving the values in two Lists which I use later to create placemarks for each point.
Here is the for loop in the Handler1.ashx.cs

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
          {
              string lng = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].ToString();
              string lat = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].ToString();

              latList.Add(lat);
              longList.Add(lng);
          }
```

Then of course it complains that GridView1 does not exist in the current context...

How can I use the GridView1 methods here?

Hope you can understand what I mean and give some ideas
Thanks

Comment: Where was GridView1 declared?

Comment: In another aspx page. It's WebForm2.aspx
Maybe I need something like FindControl but still couldn't do it..

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference page controls in an ASHX.

You have two options:

1) Bundle up the values from the grid in javascript and call the ashx with those values (we use this approach extensively).

2) Change your page to postback or partial postback and then call a static function in the ashx page (if that is where your logic is centralized) with the values from the grid control.

Comment: Thanks dude.. by static function do you mean a javascript and then calling it in the ashx? And yes the ashx is all the logic.

Comment: @Pepys: If you have your page postback instead of calling the ashx from javascript in the page, then you can move the logic in the ashx code-behind static and call those static functions from your page's codebehind. We do this all of the time.

Comment: Hmm that sounds doable :) but since i'm kinda new to asp.net, do u have some links with more info and tutorials maybe ?
Thanks a lot :)